# Using Spring Batch to horizontally scale external process execution

Tags: java, parallel-processing, spring-batch, scalability

One of the steps in our job involves running an external process (R in this case) to do some processing on large files in the file system. The external process will then output files which then get fed back into the Spring Batch system.

The external process can take several minutes for each task to complete. We would effectively launch the external process for every file to be processed, so there could easily be on the order of dozens or hundreds of these executions during the life of the overall job. We would like to scale this execution horizontally (and vertically).

Using Spring Batch, would either Remote Chunking or Remote Partitioning be a viable solution for this step? The system really just needs to say "For each of these input files, launch an R script to process it", so there really is not any item or chunk-oriented processing involved.

Remote Chunking/Partitioning has been proving difficult to implement in a sensible manner for this without seeming like overkill. I have thought about instead making this task run "out of band". For example, in the Processor, I would put each "external task" on a JMS queue, let something pull it off and process it and wait for a response that it has finished. This seems like it would be a lot easier than using Remote Chunking/Partitioning.

Other alternative solutions besides Spring Batch are welcome too, but I would like to focus on integrating this solution with Spring Batch for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing is exactly what partitioning does.  Even your "out of band" option still falls into what partitioning does.

Let's walk through what I would expect the job to look like.

**Job and Master Step**

The job, as you noted, is a single step job.  What I would envision is that the single step is a partitioned step.  With a partitioned step, the two main pieces you need to configure are the `Partitioner` (the component that knows how to divide the work up) and the `PartitionHandler` (the component that knows how to send the work to the workers).  For the `Partitioner`, I'd expect using the [`MultiResourcePartitioner`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/partition/support/MultiResourcePartitioner.html) would work.  This `Partitioner` implementation provided by Spring Batch creates one partition per file as defined by it's configuration.

The `PartitionHandler` is where you choose if you're going to be executing the slaves locally (via the [`TaskExecutorPartitionHandler`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/partition/support/TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.html)) or remotely (via the [`MessageChannelPartitionHandler`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/integration/partition/MessageChannelPartitionHandler.html)).  The `PartitionHandler` is also responsible for aggregating the results of the executing slaves into a single status so the step's result can be evaluated.

**Slave Step**

For the slave step, there are two pieces.  The first is the configuration of the step itself.  This is no different than if you were running the step in line.  In this example, I'd expect you to use the [`SystemCommandTasklet`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/step/tasklet/SystemCommandTasklet.html) to run your R process (unless you're running it on the JVM).

How the step is launched is dependent upon remote vs local partitioning but is also straight forward.

For the record, I did a talk a while back demonstrating remote partitioning that's available on YouTube here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CYTj5YT7CZU  The code for that demo is also available on Github here: https://github.com/mminella/Spring-Batch-Talk-2.0

Comment: Thanks for the response, Michael. I think my confusion mainly revolved around figuring out how to get the remote partitioning to work with this use case using the reader/processor/writer model, since that is what most of the examples were leading me towards. With what you are describing, it sounds like there would be no reader or writer in the slave step, which makes sense.

I was also concerned about running into timeouts if the "process" step was designed to be a simple transformation step of a single record, but perhaps that is not an issue here.

Comment: As a follow-up question with what you are suggesting, how would I go about providing the resources to the MultiResourcePartitioner? These will change depending on the currently running job. Would it work to construct the Partitioner in its own `@Bean` annotated factory method and then also set `@JobScope` and inject the jobParameters that way? I've only see `@JobScope` and `@StepScope` used in readers and writers but not for things like the partitioner.

Comment: You got it.  They can really be used on any object that you need it's own instance for a step or job.